# C++ Structure default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I'm using a part of autoit source code
I have a structure :

```
typedef struct
{
    WPARAM  wParam;                             // Hotkey ID
    LPARAM  lParam;                             // Key and modifiers (control, alt, etc)
    luabridge::LuaRef lFunction;                // Function to call
} HotKeyDetails;
```

I make an array of this structure in my class private storage :

```
static HotKeyDetails    *m_HotKeyDetails[MAXHOTKEYS];   // Array for tracking hotkey details
```

And when I wanna create a new of this structure :

```
m_HotKeyDetails[nFreeHandle] = new HotKeyDetails;   // Create new entry
```

I get this error :

```
1>Scripts.cpp(1216): error C2512: 'HotKeyDetails' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

How ever I just copy/pasted code from autoit source code but in there it will compile well
Whats wrong with that

Comment: Like the error said: there is no default constructor. Your compiler doesn't know how to initalize `lFunction`. If you provide an constructor to `HotKeyDetails`, you can call `new HotkeyDetails()` just like you did.

Comment: @Constantin How can I provide an default constructor for it ? Want all of them to be initialized to null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the class `luabridge::LuaRef` has no default constructor (see the [documentation](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s4.1)), so the compiler can't generate a default constructor for `HotKeyDetails` either.

To fix this, just add a constructor; for example:

```
struct HotKeyDetails {
    WPARAM  wParam;                             // Hotkey ID
    LPARAM  lParam;                             // Key and modifiers (control, alt, etc)
    luabridge::LuaRef lFunction;                // Function to call

    explicit HotKeyDetails(lua_State* L): wParam(NULL), lParam(NULL), lFunction(L) {}
};
```

If you prefer to allow this struct to be default constructible, then you'll have to make `lFunction` a pointer:

```
struct HotKeyDetails {
    WPARAM  wParam;                             // Hotkey ID
    LPARAM  lParam;                             // Key and modifiers (control, alt, etc)
    luabridge::LuaRef *lFunction;               // Function to call

    HotKeyDetails(): wParam(NULL), lParam(NULL), lFunction(NULL) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add a default constructor to the HotKeyDetails struct. Like:

```
struct HotKeyDetails
{
    HotKeyDetails() : wParam(0), lParam(0), lFunction(L) {}

    WPARAM  wParam;                             // Hotkey ID
    LPARAM  lParam;                             // Key and modifiers (control, alt, etc)
    luabridge::LuaRef lFunction;                // Function to call
} ;
```

However you will need to provide/track the `lua_State* L` variable which was provided by your application if you want to use this struct in an array.